# Unable to implement NotificationListenerService, because of unresolved class in Manifest-file

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am very new to Android Development. I am trying to make functionality where the value of a textView changes when a notification pops up. 
I found the NotificationListenerService:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

The first step is to copy-paste the following code into the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
           android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
 </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Unfortunately, in my Manifest-file "NotificationListenerService" and "@string/service_name" are marked in red, and it says "Unresolved class NotificationListener". Does anyone know what is wrong?

I have not created a NotificatonListener-class. Even when I do so the error changes to: "NotificationListener is not assignable to 'android.app.service'.

Comment: Have you create NotificationListener.java class

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried that, but then the error changes to "NotificationListener is not assignable to 'android.app.service'"

Comment: It needs to `extends NotificationListenerService`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General comment: hitting Alt+Enter once focused on red-highlighted area (usually) shows possible resolutions.

In your case, once applied over "android:name=".NotificationListener" you should be able to create class that extends Service, thus should be assignable to 'android.app.service'.
You should then encounter another issue 'public class NotificationListener extends Service' marked red. Alt+Enter again and 'Implement methods' -> 'onBind' should be generated.

For '@string/service_name' - either create a string resource or use any other string (e.g. "my_service_tag" or whatever).

Please follow the attached docs and have a look on 'onListenerConnected'. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was very helpful :) will accept your answer